# Flash compiler returns error "Source path does not resolve to a valid directory"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

I have a .fla file and when I was to compile it and see resulting SWF (ctrl + Enter) I get the following Warning:

"Warning: Source path './src' does not resolve to a valid directory"

Any idea what the problem can be? 
this even used to work properly before.

I am using Adobe Flash CC.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried giving it a full path rather than a relative one?

Comment: Sounds like the relative path to the 'src' directory isn't valid.  Have you verified that the 'src' directory exists at the same location as your .FLA file?

Comment: I dont know how to change/edit/check the field where this path is set.

Comment: that path has been set either in the publish settings, library or source path settings (actionscript 3 settings)

Comment: regardless of where this is set, the compiler is stating that the src folder is invalid and is being referenced at the same location as the .fla, hence the "./" preceding the 'swf' folder name.  If there is no folder named 'src' in the same directory that your .fla is located, then _that_ is your problem.  So I'll ask again, have you checked that a folder named 'src' exists within the same folder that your .fla is saved?

Comment: i checked and the "src" folder is missing from the same dir as the .fla file.

Comment: but I have one outside my "assets" folder where the .fla is located. However, even after I copy the "src" folder next to the .fla, I still get black scene - but no warnings.

Comment: Well if you  are getting no warnings now, but a black scene, then you have an different, possibly unrelated issue, but at least your compiler problems are now resolved.